# Date Range Regex in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Looking for a regular expression in Notepad++ to find any years outside of the year range: `1980-2019`

This will find WITHIN the year range I'm looking for, but I can't find outside of the range.

```
[1-9]\d{4,}|19[8,9][0-9]|[1-9]\d{4,}|20[0,1][0-9]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post and add examples of data that should be matched and data that should be rejected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't particularly think regex is suitable for this, but this might work:

```
(?![1-9]\d{4,}|19[8,9][0-9]|[1-9]\d{4,}|20[0,1][0-9])\b\d+
```

I simply negated your regex with a negative lookahead, and matched the digits with `\d+`. This will match any number of digits, because technically the year 1 is also outside of the range 1980-2019. If you only want 4 digit years, simply change `+` to `{4}`.

Comment: That works PERFECTLY!!!! I just changed the + to {4} as you mentioned, and added it into my previous regex which kept the date format and time, and it's able to find the exact dates that I need to change!!!

THANKS SO MUCH! This will save me so much time in the future, hunting down bad year entries!

Comment: @Tim if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: It seems because I don't have a reputation of at least 15, it doesn't show publicly. But it says that it is recorded. Strange system.

Comment: @Tim not the up arrow. I mean the checkmark. You can click the checkmark even without 15 rep.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. First time Poster